# Can't get response data from API

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I used volley to get data from api.
As a result it throws an 403 response error (Though the api is valid and has a status 200)

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=f7b3a441dc7b436087bdc6fbf20946b2";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        response -> {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                if(jsonArray.length()>0){
                    for(int i =0; i < 10; i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String nTitle = jsonObject1.getString("title");
                        data.add(new ModelRV(nTitle));
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't fetch data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: Is your device connected to internet? 403 is forbidden error. Does the API accepts the request user-agent?

Comment: ofcourse device is connected to internet, but it logs out the 403 error and i don't think so the issue from api side as it works perfect, Maybe any client side issues? and the code snippet is given above

Comment: I would propose using Retrofit with LoggingInterceptor and automatic deserialization using GSON or Jackson. Then you can examine your logs much closer and see what's wrong

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I found that combination of libraries really good for solving such problems. You have to do some googling, but you'll figure it out :-)

Comment: Yeah, I got through using retrofit and it did! Thanks Mate! :) @Vucko

Comment: Hehe, cool man! It took a few days, but hopefully it was worth it. Good job! Cheers.